# jQuery ajax ".done" callbacks not firing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The following jQuery code (postData) posts data to a simple php file and on completion calls sendReply or sendFail.  I have a console.log in the postData function and the sendReply and sendFail callbacks also have console.log.  The first console.log shows in the FF dev console, the callbacks do not.

The php file is very simple because I'm new to posting to php with jQuery and I want to test the callback function before I go on.

Here is the jQuery:

```
<form>

// form elements here, omitted for brevity
 // the jQuery is called from a button click event

<div class="btn_div">
<button class="btn_joinnow" id="btn_submit" style="color:rgb(255,255,255)" onClick="postData(event)">Click to submit data</button></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function postData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var datastring = $("#echo_test").serialize();
    console.log("Okay, I'm starting")
    return $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "echo_test.php",
       data: {post: datastring}
    });
}

function sendReply() {
    console.log("Okay, I'm done"); }

function sendFail() {
    console.log("Okay, I failed"); }

postData().done(sendReply, sendFail);

</script>

</form>
```

I could chain the callbacks, but then event.preventDefault does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function postData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var datastring = $("#echo_test").serialize();
    console.log("Okay, I'm starting")
    return $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "echo_test.php",
       data: {post: datastring}
    });.done(function() {
    console.log("Okay, I'm done");
    }).fail(function() {
    console.log("Okay, I failed");
});
}
```

Here is the ultra-simple php:

```
<?php
echo "Hello world";
?>
```

Why doesn't eithier callback function execute on completion?  Is it the jQuery or the php function?  The Firefox dev console shows this about the php:

```
XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location: (file location) Line Number 4, Column 1:
```

I am working on my local (Windows) machine, not on my cloud server.  Is that the entire problem?

Thanks very much for any insights.

Comment: `;.done` is a __syntax error__.

Comment: The behaviour you are after is not `done(success, failure)` but `then(success, failure)`

Comment: @u_mulder, if I remove that, the event.preventDefault does not work.

Comment: If you don't remove that, your entire script will stop working once javascript encounters that syntax error

Comment: You know what is __syntax error__, right?

Comment: @taplar, I changed it to then but same behavior

Comment: @u_mulder, as I said when I remove it the event.preventDefault does not work.  Yes, of course I know what a syntax error is.

Comment: If you know what it is, then it is slightly odd that you seem to be arguing in opposition of fixing it.  "If I remove it, X stops working" suggest you are saying you have to leave it in for something to work.  Which is not a valid argument

Comment: My `then(success, failure)` comment was in reference to the first snippet.

Comment: Give me a second, I'll reply back after I've done it.

Comment: @Taplar, I changed the line postData().done(sendReply, sendFail); to postData().then(sendReply, sendFail); - still doesn't fire.

Comment: Mmm, your first snippet, you are not passing in an event to the method.  And in fact in that case there is no event.  You are just calling the method.  So the argument would need to be removed and the preventDefault removed.  Or do an if check to verify it exists, before calling preventDefault on it

Comment: onClick="postData(event)" sends the event; and "function postData(event)" passes it in.  If I remove preventDefault, we link to a new url (blank screen).  That's what I don't want.

Comment: `postData().then(sendReply, sendFail);` <= this line.  There is no event

Comment: I see.  Let me try that now.  The preventDefault is in the function itself, not the callback, but I'll post back in a minute.

Comment: postData(event).then(sendReply, sendFail);  still doesn't work.  event.preventDefault does, but no callback fires.

Comment: You're missing the point.  You do not have an event in that case to pass in.  You only have an event in the case of the inline binding.  So you cannot just pass `event` into the method and expect it to exist.  That is why your logic should do an if check before it tries to prevent default.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the comment.  I upvoted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version with some small tweaks since the php you have does not care about the data you post.

To keep it as a post, I changed it to jsonplaceholder and after clicking you can see the return response in the console.

```html
<form>
<div class="btn_div">
<button href="google.com"  class="btn_joinnow" id="btn_submit" style="color:rgb(255,255,255)">Click to submit data

    </button></div>
</form>
```

I added a link to google to make sure the preventDefault does work.

```
$("#btn_submit").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var datastring = JSON.stringify({
        title: 'foo',
        body: 'bar',
        userId: 1
    });
    console.log("Okay, I'm starting");
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
        data: {post: datastring},
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Okay, I failed" + error);
        }
    });
});
```

If you want it simpler, with a GET, here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/persianphilosopher/pen/BeVOeR).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I see you use an href instead of an onclick event.  I'll try your example now and let you know what happens.

Comment: It works as you show above.  When I change the url to my php file echo_test.php I do get the "Okay, I failed[object Object]" so suggests the problem is in my php.  Thanks very much once again.  I chose your answer as the best and upvoted it.

Comment: Glad to hear that. The reason you are getting object Object as answer is that your php is sending an echo object. If you want to keep the php response as text (and not json), change the success function to function(responseText) and console.log(responseText) and it should work